# Create union type based on array of types

Tags: typescript, generics, union, typescript-generics

Is it possible to define union type like this:

```
Union<T extends any[]> = // something...
```

and would be used like

```
Union<[string, number]> // would create (string | number)
```

I know I can immediatelly define union above, but I need it for usage in generics where it would end up being something like `Union<[TDynamic, UDynamic]>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following type:

```
type Union<T extends any[]> = T extends (infer U)[] ? U : never;
```

This is actually basically the same type as `Unpacked` defined in the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types), and works because a type tuple becomes a type union in this case.

```
type X1 = Union<[number, string]>; // string | number
type X2 = Union<[number, number]>; // number
type X3 = Union<[number]>; // number
```

If you're on an older TypeScript version which does not support `infer`, you can also use:

```
type Union<T extends any[]> = T[number];
```

Comment: Perfect, any way to be able to define like Union<number, string> (to support dynamic number of generic arguments so I don't have to add array definition)?

Comment: If you can write `Union<T1, T2>`, why not write `T1 | T2` directly? I don't think for that you need a separate type.

Comment: Because I'll use it in generic definition but I get your point, because I won't be able to pass it like that anyway in generic definition (will have array of dynamic types). One more question if you don't mind - is it possible to create Intersection type (same way as above Union)?

Comment: You can possibly get that to work using @jcalz's `UnionToIntersection` trick: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286/1675492